# Write to a file whose path does not exist yet

Tags: bash, terminal, directory

I want to write to a file `file.txt` using terminal in

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4...dirN/file.txt
```

The path `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4...dirN/` does not exist. How can I write to this file so that the path gets created on the fly?

Comment: Better suited to superuser.stackexchange.com where they will tell you about mkdir -p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `mkdir -p` like ths:

```
mkdir -p /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4...dirN/
```

The `-p` creates the whole directory structure if it does not exist. As explained in the mkdir man page:

> Create intermediate directories as required.  If this option is not
>   specified, the full path prefix of each operand must already exist. 
>   On the other hand, with this option specified, no error will be
>   reported if a directory given as an operand already exists. 
>   Intermediate directories are created with permission bits of rwxrwxrwx
>   (0777) as modified by the current umask, plus write and search
>   permission for the owner.

And here it is all used in one small shell script; only going up to `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/` for this example:

```
if [ ! -d /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/ ]; then
  mkdir -p /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/;
fi;
echo "Hello world" >> /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file.txt
```

Or to make it a bit more flexible, you can add variables & even use `dirname` to get the file basepath:

```
// Set the filename.
FILENAME="/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file.txt"

// Get the directory basepath by using dirname.
DIRECTORY=$(dirname ${FILENAME})

// If the directory does not exist, create it.
if [ ! -d ${DIRECTORY} ]; then
  mkdir -p ${DIRECTORY};
fi

// Now do something like appending text a filename in that directory.
echo "Hello world" >>  ${FILENAME}
```

Comment: Also I should be able to write to that file.

Answer (score 1):

Separately create directory then create the file:

```
mkdir -p "/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4...dirN" && : >> /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4...dirN/file.txt
```

Note: If you just want to make sure that `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4...dirN/file.txt` would exist, you can create a function like this:

```
function summon {
    mkdir -p "${1%/*}" && : >> "$1"
}

# Application:

FILE="/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4.txt"

if summon "$FILE"; then
    # Do something with "$FILE"
    : ...
else
    echo "Failed to prepare file $FILE".
fi
```

Comment: Why did you choose the function name as "summon"?